# Comment on dit "not anymore" en Français?

Tags: grammaire, traduction, questions

Quand on pose la question par exemple: fumez-vous toujours? Si la réponse est "not anymore" comment on le dit en français correctement comme en anglais?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> - Je ne fume plus. Plus maintenant
> - J'ai arreté de fumer!

Comment: Je veux dire une traduction identique à not anymore

Comment: Plus maintenant

Comment: Merciiii voila c'est ce que je cherchais

Answer (score 6):

To elaborate and make the question less of a translation one, here's a fun note: French expresses a lot of different ideas of negation using the same construction. You've heard of

> ne ... pas

Well, consider *pas* as the "vanilla" flavour of a negative sentence. You now have a lot of different flavours you can swap in, such as:

> ne ... guère (hardly)
>
> Il ne pense guère à sa femme.
>
> ne ... pas non plus (either; neither)
>
> Elle ne pense pas à lui non plus !

There are quite a number of these:

> ne ... jamais (never)
>
> ne ... que (only; nothing except)
>
> ne ... pas encore (not yet)
>
> ne ... point (not at all)
>
> ne ... ni ... ni (neither ... nor ... nor)

Some of these can also be nouns and act as the subject of the sentence:

> ne ... personne (nobody)
>
> Personne ne veut des bananes vertes.
>
> ne ... rien (nothing)
>
> Rien n'est comme il semble.
>
> ne ... aucun (none; not a single one)
>
> Aucun des droits ne doit être franchi.

Sometimes they can even be combined:

> Rien n'existe que l'homme dans l'univers.

And, finally, here's the one you're looking for. :)

> ne ... plus (not anymore)
>
> Je ne veux plus trouver une façon de nier la phrase.

When you're looking for an English phrase with the word "not", or that otherwise has a negative sense, check if there's a replacement for "pas" that will do the job!

As a final note, be aware that "ne" will often or even usually drop out in spoken French. Thus, in such contexts you should understand "jamais", "plus", "rien" as "never", "not anymore", "nothing", etc., following verbs.

> Je veux plus danser.
>
> I don't want to dance anymore.

Comment: I corrected "elle ne pense pas de lui non plus" in "elle ne pense pas à lui non plus".

Comment: +1 for the nice coverage of negations! Another one that I usually have trouble using correctly is "ne...ni ...[ni]."

Comment: Added that one to the list. (For usage as object: "Je ne veux ni la soupe ni la salade." For usage as subject: "Ni la soupe ni la salade ne m'intéresse.")