# Negation in French

Tags: grammaire, négation

"N'aura nul lieu" translated to English directly means "shall not have no place". But it seems to mean "shall have no place". So I wonder how negation works in French.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***N'aura nul lieu*** is quite outdated. Modern French rather uses either ***n'aura aucun lieu*** or ***n'aura nulle part***.

In any case, this is not a double negation example but just a split negative where both ***ne*** and ***nul(le)/aucun*** are used to negate "***aura un lieu***/***aura quelque part***" (i.e. will have "somewhere" vs will have "nowhere").

A real double negation would have been ***n'aura pas nul lieu***: will have "**no nowhere**".

See: [Why does French use a "split negative"?](https://french.stackexchange.com/q/884/1109)
[Does `ne` and `pas` have a different meaning?](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/44879/does-ne-and-pas-have-a-different-meaning/44880#44880) [Does "ne" not negate words that are already negative?](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/44610/does-ne-not-negate-words-that-are-already-negative)

Comment: No, this is not double negation. But it is a difference between English and French since the direct translation in English is like "shall not have no place", right?

Comment: A direct translation of what?

Comment: A direct translation of "n'aura aucun lieu" is "shall not have no place".

Comment: Translates to "will have no place".

Comment: Yes, I know that. I mean "n'aura" is translated directly to "shall not have".

Comment: As far as spoken/casual French is concerned, *aura* and *n'aura* can be interchangeable. You need a complete phrase to assert the meaning.

Comment: Does "aucun" also mean "any" in English? So a direct translation of "n'aura aucun lieu" is "shall not have any place", which is consistent with English (completely).

Comment: *Aucun* can mean "none", "any", or even "some". Context is everything.